# Appengine not compiling my .jspx files

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, jspx

I have a little app that runs fine on local dev appengine, but appengine itself is not processing my .jspx files.

The jspx files are in WEB-INF so they should not be excluded by appengine (as a static resource)

I am using Apache Tiles to define my views.

So the html produced looks like this:

```
<html 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
    >  
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />  
    <jsp:directive.page isELIgnored="false"/>
```

(etc etc)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went on a quest and found the answer to my own question...

Appengine precompiles all JSP's at deploy time.

The current version (1.3.4) of Appengine does not let the Jasper compiler kick in if no .jsp files are found in the webapp. However, if you add a dummy.jsp file to the webapp, the Jasper compiler will actually be started and it will pick up .jspx files.

Apparently, this is a known issue for Google's appengine team.

Credits to [Stefan Schmidt @ Springsource](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/ROO-996?focusedCommentId=54678&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_54678) who was given the inside scoop from Google's Appengine team :)

Answer (score 1):

see http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/367cc9d6c9815535?pli=1

Comment: i saw that post :) like i said, my JSPx files are in WEB-INF so they're not excluded.